# how to set isdebugenabled in NLog

Tags: asp.net, nlog

I try to find a way to set isdebugenabled false or true in configuration file,

so I can turn it on or off whenever I need. Thanks !

Comment: Wouldn't setting the log level to a higher value (or Off) accomplish the same thing?

Comment: Well, I think if I know how to set isdebugenabled, I can use it in the code like if (isdebugenabled) blah blah blah. Then it might improve the performance somehow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using a really simple logging setup

```
<targets>
  <target xsi:type="File"
          name="debug"
          fileName="c:\temp\debug.txt"
          layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}" 
  />
</targets>

<rules>
  <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="debug" />
</rules>
```

And an equally simple code sample

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var logger = new NLog.LogFactory().GetCurrentClassLogger();

        if (logger.IsDebugEnabled)
        {
            logger.Debug("this is a debug message");
        }

        logger.Debug("this is another debug message");
    }
}
```

When `minLevel` is set to Debug or Trace, both `logger.Debug` statements will write to the log.   If you raise `minLevel` to a higher level (Info, Warn, Off) neither statement will be written to the log.   `logger.Debug` checks `IsDebugEnabled` (which is inferred from the log level).

You can certainly get a performance increase (in cases where you are going to be logging calculated values and not just strings) by checking `IsDebugEnabled`, and changing `minLevel` for the logger is the way to toggle this.

Comment: I thought NLog would have a configuration setting called enabledebug='false'. They should indicate this more obvious in the document. Thanks for helping !